# Merge array of hashes where condition is met

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
array = [{:date=>Sun, 10 Aug 2014, :slots=>[]},
 {:date=>Mon, 11 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00"]},
 {:date=>Fri, 15 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00"]},
 {:date=>Sat, 16 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00"]},
 {:date=>Fri, 15 Aug 2014, :slots=>["14:30", "15:00"]}]
```

I want to merge / add :slots where :date is equal

```
 final = [{:date=>Mon, 11 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00"]},
 {:date=>Fri, 15 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "14:30", "15:00" ]},
 {:date=>Sat, 16 Aug 2014,
  :slots=>["9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00"]}]
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I want to merge / add :slots where :date is equal" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0):

```
final = array.each_with_object({}) do |hash, memo|
  memo[hash[:date]] ||= []
  memo[hash[:date]] |= hash[:slots]
end.each_with_object([]) do |(date, slots), memo|
  memo.push(date: date, slots: slots)
end
```

note that in order to run your code, I added quotes around the date objects (try pasting `Mon, 11 Aug 2014` into IRB, it causes a SyntaxError).

Anyway, what this does it:

1. Turn the array of hashes into a single hash where keys are dates and values are arrays of slots. Use `|=` ("or equals" operator) to merge in slots with the same date.
2. Turn the hash back into the original format (array of hashes)

Comment: thanks for the help!
I finally managed with:
 # set key vlue as date => slots
   `intermediate_array = array.map do |x| 
      {x[:date] => x[:slots]}
    end`
    merge where key is same
    `x.inject{|y, z| y.merge(z) { |k, old, new| old+new}}`

Comment: Oh, cool, I forgot about the block that can be passed to `merge`.. By the way, if you feel like you figured it out yourself you can make your own answer and accept it in a few days. It helps keep the questions list clean and people won't visit this thinking it's unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

One way to return an array of hashes with merged `slot` values would be to generate a new array, iterate through the original, compare date values, and merge slots to the new array when appropriate:

```
def merge_slots(array)
  result = []

  array.each do |hash|
    result_dates = result.map { |h| h[:date] }
    array_dates = array.map { |h| h[:date] }

    if matching_index = result_dates.find_index(hash[:date])
      matching_hash = array[matching_index]
      matching_hash[:slots] = matching_hash[:slots] | hash[:slots]
    else
      result << hash
    end
  end

  result
end

final = merge_slots(your_array)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the help!
I finally managed with:
 # set key vlue as date => slots
   `intermediate_array = array.map do |x| 
      {x[:date] => x[:slots]}
    end`
    merge where key is same
    `x.inject{|y, z| y.merge(z) { |k, old, new| old+new}}`